# Why aren't files being ignored by Git?

Tags: git

I want Git to ignore all files named `build-impl.xml` in my project.

To do this I added `*build-impl.xml` to `.gitignore`

However Git still shows the files as being modified:

```
$ git status    
modified:   TMA02Q1Server/nbproject/build-impl.xml
modified:   TMA2Q1Client/nbproject/build-impl.xml
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I was not aware the files were being tracked - by asking this question I was helped to understand why I wasn't getting the result as expected. This question may help people in a similar situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.gitignore does not apply to files that are already being tracked.

If you delete the file from disk, commit it, and then restore the file to its original location, git will stop tracking it.

Or, run `git rm --cached TMA02Q1Server/nbproject/build-impl.xml`

Comment: Is there another way to do it without deleting the file?

Comment: @NRKirby moving them to another location and then move them back?